# How to fit a polynomial when the values of derivatives are constrained?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, polynomials, scipy-optimize

Is there an easy way to get a solution where there is a constraint on the maximum value of a derivative of a polynomial function `f(x)`, for a certain range of values for `x`?

Like was answered to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469889/how-to-fit-a-polynomial-with-some-of-the-coefficients-constrained), `curve_fit` from `scipy.optimize` can deal with constraints on the individual coefficients, like in the following example:

```
def func(x, a, b, c, d):
  return a + b * x + c * x ** 2 + d * x ** 3

x = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  4.0,  5.0])
y = np.array([0.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, -0.8, -1.0])

popt_cons, _ = curve_fit(func, x, y, bounds=([-np.inf, 2, -np.inf, -np.inf], [np.inf, 2.001, np.inf, np.inf]))
print(popt_cons)
>>> [-0.14331349  2.         -0.95913556  0.10494372]
```

But what if I wanted the best fit polynomial where there is a constraint on for example the maximum value of the acceleration (second derivative) for a certain range of `x` values?
That means, by integrating the function twice, that there is a constraint on the value of `2*c + 6*d*x` for lets say, `x` between `0` to `10`.
Is there a method to do this, or do I have to build this from scratch?

Comment: I think you'll have to build it - seems to me that it's just a matter of adding constraints. Maybe look at sympy to get the derivatives automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `curve_fit` method doesn't support additional constraints. However, you could implement a non-linear least-squares problem

```
min ||f(x, coeffs) - y||^2

s.t.    lb <= coeffs <= ub
     f''(x, coeffs) <= max_val for all x_lb <= x <= x_ub
```

with additional constraints and solve it with [`minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). Here's an example of how it could be done by means of [`np.polyval`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html) and [`np.polyder`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyder.html):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

x = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  4.0,  5.0])
y = np.array([0.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, -0.8, -1.0])

def objective(coeffs):
    return np.linalg.norm(np.polyval(coeffs, x) - y)

def constraint(coeffs, deriv_order, x_lb, x_ub, max_val):
    deriv_coeffs = np.polyder(coeffs, deriv_order)
    # Evaluate the derivative for all x_lb <= x <= x_ub
    deriv_value = np.polyval(deriv_coeffs, x[(x >= x_lb) & (x <= x_ub)])
    return -1.0*deriv_value + max_val

# Each inequality constraint has the form fun(x) >= 0
cons = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda coeffs: constraint(coeffs, 2, 0.0, 3.0, 20)}]
bnds = [(-np.inf, np.inf), (2, 5.001), (-np.inf, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.inf)]

poly_degree = 3
res = minimize(objective, x0=2.0*np.ones(poly_degree+1), bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
```

Note that each inequality constraint has the form `fun(x) >= 0`, i.e. we have `-f''(x, coeffs) + max_val >= 0` and we used `x_lb = 0.0`, `x_ub = 3.0` and `max_val = 20` for the second derivative. Finally, `res.x` contains the polynomial coefficients.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing I would change is to change
`deriv_value = np.polyval(deriv_coeffs, x[(x >= x_lb) & (x <= x_ub)])`
to
`x_eval = np.arange(x_lb,x_ub,0.1)
deriv_value = np.polyval(deriv_coeffs, x_eval)`
such that values for `x` outside of the known datapoints can be evaluated.